# Basic properties of smooth curves

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose $\Gamma$ is simple smooth closed curve parametrized by $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Gamma.$ Let $$\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)=(t-s)F(t,s)\,\,\,\,t,s\in[0,1].$$
Can we conclude that $|F(t,s)|>0$ for all $t,s\in[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the case $s=t$?  Then no, your equation does not determine $F(t,t)$.  If in addition you require $F(t,s)$ to be continuous, then $F(t,t) = \gamma'(t)$;  now $\gamma'(t) \ne 0$ is sometimes included as part of the definition of "smooth curve", sometimes not.